# Avoid repetition of the word "contain"

Tags: repetition

What I wrote is:

"However, just as any other data carrier, images not only contain important data, but also such of lesser significance to us. "

I want to say that images not only contain important data, but they also contain data of lesser significance. How can I write it without repeating "contain" and make the whole sentence sound more natural?

Comment: "images contain important and extraneous data." or even more succinctly: "images contain data."

Comment: If all you care about is not repeating the word *contain*, why not just delete that from "what you want to say" and resequence accordingly? Giving *Images contain not only important data, but also data of lesser significance*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Like any data carrier, however, images contain very important data alongside data of lesser significance.